# weird interpretation of vertical spacing macros in contents of lrbox / minipage / colorbox

Tags: spacing

I know I have seen this typesetting problem before, but I cannot find a solution.  latex can be quite counterintuitive.  All I am trying to do is to create a \panel{} header-type macro that works inside a slightly-modified table.  the \panel should increase the spacing from the previous tabular and reduce it to the next tabular.

I have stripped down an example to show the issue.  how does one define a \panel macro that does what is expected of it?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newsavebox{\selvesteboxtwo}
\newenvironment{colboxfigtbl}
  {
   \begin{lrbox}{\selvesteboxtwo}%
   \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\columnwidth-2\fboxsep-4em\relax}}
  {
   \end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
   \begin{center}%
     \fcolorbox{blue}{yellow}{\usebox{\selvesteboxtwo}}%%real life do more
   \end{center} 
  }

\newenvironment{newtable}[1][]{%
  \begin{table}%
    \begin{center}%
      \begin{colboxfigtbl}
      }{%
      \end{colboxfigtbl}%
    \end{center}%
  \end{table}
}

\newcommand{\panel}[2]{%
  \par\bigskip%
  \begin{center} \textbf{Panel #1:} #2 \end{center}%
  \par\vspace*{-1.5\baselineskip}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{newtable}

  \panel{A}{This is a bad panel}

  \begin{center}\begin{tabular}{l r} \toprule A & B \\ \bottomrule \end{tabular} \end{center}

  \panel{B}{This is a better panel}

  \begin{center}\begin{tabular}{l r} \toprule A & B \\  \bottomrule \end{tabular} \end{center}

  \panel{C}{This is a better panel}

  \begin{center}\begin{tabular}{l r} \toprule A & B \\  \bottomrule \end{tabular} \end{center}

\end{newtable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frequently, nesting environments together can be tricky, because environments tend to add space above and below their content.  On top of that, some environments try to get clever and subtract out extra space that a nested environment has inserted.  In a case like yours, the answer is straightforward: in the `\newtable` environment, which already invokes the `table` environment, replace the nested `\begin{center}...\end{center}` environment with `\centering...`, which is a macro form that achieves the same effect, without an environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newsavebox{\selvesteboxtwo}
\newenvironment{colboxfigtbl}
  {
   \begin{lrbox}{\selvesteboxtwo}%
   \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\columnwidth-2\fboxsep-4em\relax}}
  {
   \end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
   \begin{center}%
     \fcolorbox{blue}{yellow}{\usebox{\selvesteboxtwo}}%%real life do more
   \end{center} 
  }

\newenvironment{newtable}[1][]{%
  \begin{table}%
    \centering%\begin{center}%
      \begin{colboxfigtbl}
      }{%
      \end{colboxfigtbl}%
%    \end{center}%
  \end{table}
}

\newcommand{\panel}[2]{%
  \par\bigskip%
  \begin{center} \textbf{Panel #1:} #2 \end{center}%
  \par\vspace*{-1.5\baselineskip}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{newtable}

  \panel{A}{This is a bad panel}

  \begin{center}\begin{tabular}{l r} \toprule A & B \\ \bottomrule \end{tabular} \end{center}

  \panel{B}{This is a better panel}

  \begin{center}\begin{tabular}{l r} \toprule A & B \\  \bottomrule \end{tabular} \end{center}

  \panel{C}{This is a better panel}

  \begin{center}\begin{tabular}{l r} \toprule A & B \\  \bottomrule \end{tabular} \end{center}

\end{newtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks.  given cleverness of environments, I guess this is always trial and error, without clear and easy rules...